# Resizing Text on Browser Resize

Tags: html, css

Firstly, excuse my absolute lack of knowledge, I'm trying to make a website for the first time and have very little training..

I'm trying to get my text within a div to resize vertically when the browser window is resized. So far I've used purely HTML and CSS (would be willing to use something else to do this, however might need some advice as to how to implement it!).

From what I've read I thought setting the width and height tags using a percentage would work, but it is only working for horizontal resizing. The image within the div resizes, however the text links dont.

I wanted the position of the div to be fixed, so it doesn't scroll with the rest of the page content. Unsure whether that stops me being able to resize though

Here is my CSS for the div:

```
#logo {
width:10%;
height:auto;
position:fixed;
top:1%;
left:1%;
text-align:left;
float:left;
font-family:Dekar, arial, serif;
font-size:1.5em;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Again sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: Take a look at media queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: These specify "width" can the same results be achieved replacing "width" with "height"?

Comment: I had a good look at the media query stuff, but it appears (to me, I could be incorrect) that the specification is based on the device size  rather than the browser window size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Resize When Browser Resized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716680/text-resize-when-browser-resized)

Answer (score 0):

As you are willing to use something else then HTML and CSS, I would suggest using jQuery which is a javascript library ([jQuery website](http://jquery.com)) and download a plugin called FitText ([website](http://fittextjs.com)) which resizes your text.